# Is 'which' command always showing the right file / which binary is really being run?

Tags: bash, ubuntu-12.04, path

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I have apparently messed up my system with various versions of [duplicity](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/) installations:

- first I had 0.6.18 installed from the default repo,
- then I tried using 0.6.23 from [the PPA](https://launchpad.net/~duplicity-team/+archive/ppa)
- in the end I built 0.6.24 from the source and installed it

(I list this for completeness but I don't really think this is `duplicity`-specific.)

Now my system behaves like this:

```
root@host:~# duplicity -V
duplicity 0.6.24

root@host:~# which -a duplicity
/usr/bin/duplicity

root@host:~# /usr/bin/duplicity -V
duplicity 0.6.24

root@host:~# head /usr/bin/duplicity
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
# -*- Mode:Python; indent-tabs-mode:nil; tab-width:4 -*-
#
# duplicity -- Encrypted bandwidth efficient backup
# Version 0.6.23 released $reldate
#
# Copyright 2002 Ben Escoto <ben@emerose.org>
# Copyright 2007 Kenneth Loafman <kenneth@loafman.com>
#
# This file is part of duplicity.
```

???

Is there some kind of binary cache in Ubuntu that is being used here?

*UPDATE*:

```
root@host:~$ cat /usr/bin/duplicity | grep 24
            return 128 * 1024
    if maxopen < 1024:
        log.FatalError(_("Max open files of %s is too low, should be >= 1024.\n"
                         "Use 'ulimit -n 1024' or higher to correct.\n") % (maxopen,),
root@host:~$ cat /usr/bin/duplicity | grep 23
# Version 0.6.23 released $reldate
log.Log(u"duplicity 0.6.23 ($reldate)", verbosity)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Comments are often not in sync with the code.** You could `grep -F '0.6.24' /usr/bin/duplicity` to check this. If that doesn't give any results, it could be that the version string is stored in multiple variables, so you might want to search for `23` or `24`.

As far as I know no distro has a cache of executables. I expect the security implications would be severe.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me the sad truth about the comments but apparently this is not the case here. I'll add the results of my grepping in a moment but it seems that it really is v. 0.6.23 pointed by `which`.